# Why can't I add i386 architecture to Debian Bullseye?

Tags: debian, architecture

I try to add 32 bit (i386) architecture to my Debian Bullseye using :

```
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

But it gives me no error or no success message. When I used

```
 sudo dpkg --print-architecture
```

still gives only
am64

I have read  [add 32 bit architecture question and answer for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423083/cant-run-dpkg-add-architecture-i386-on-12-04-64-bit-to-run-eclipse-adt). Command

```
 ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/
```

gives :

```
 pkg-config-hook-config
```

When I looked inside the file it writes :

`post-invoke=if { test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = add-architecture || test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = remove-architecture; } && test -x /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook; then /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook update; fi`

So I checked that whether there is a file named **pkg-config-dpkghook** in **/usr/share/** but no, there is no such file there.

Do I have to replace the filename with **multiarch** , if not what should I do?

Comment: You (unintentionally?) made your question much less clear with that recent edit. I've rolled it back to a point where it's answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

displays your system’s *primary* architecture.

To see any additional architectures configured on the system, you need to run

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

This should show `i386` in your case.

Comment: It means the `i386` architecture is enabled, which is a reasonable proxy for 32-bit support being enabled. You’ll need to install `i386` libraries if you want to actually run `i386` binaries.